# Will I get penalty if my last section of URL will repeat?

Tags: seo

I've made system very similar to this site where `site.com/item/{id}/{name}`. Now I wonder if my `{name}` will repeat itself like in this example

```
site.com/item/1/something
site.com/item/2/something
site.com/item/3/something
```

Will I be banned from google bots for this or it is completely normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will get penalty if I will use `/{id}/{name}` if the name will repeat itself.

What I did is `/{id}-{name}`. This way it will never repeat itself and I will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the ID specify a unique row in your database? In that case, there may be instances where `name` is similar to others, but probably not ever duplicated.

If it were duplicated, however, then yes this would be duplicated content and wouldn't be good for your website. You won't get '*banned from Google bots*,' but the pages would have a low score in SERPs. Think of it as a filter, not a penalty.

Comment: I just think that name can hold string and this string can be same for multiple items. Of course `ID` will be different always, but `name` can be same for multiple items.

Comment: Then you are facing duplicated content, which is bad. Beyond that, we can't help because you aren't posting enough information about the needs and whys for your project.

Comment: what if my url will be `site.com/item/3-something` meaning `3` is unique id and `something` may be repeated multiple times?